# Issue with Blazor Web Assembly string arrays

Tags: c#, .net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly

Hoping someone can help me here. A string Array seems to form differently in Blazor Web Assembly from Blazor Server. A String Array declaration in Blazor Server is as expected.

Declaration:

```
 string[] scopeDefault = new string[] { "myString" };
```

Debug value:

```
{string[1]}
```

Now compare with Blazor Web Assembly:
Declaration (identical)

```
string[] scopeDefault = new string[] { "MyString" };
```

Debug value (wasm)

```
string[](1)
```

Note the difference in the construct of the array and the Server version does not have a length attribute. I'm using this in a function that requires an iEnumerable interface. When I try and use the string array in Blazor Server, it's fine. In WASM it breaks with "Children could not be evaluated". I've tried constructing a List and same issue.
Here is the full code including use:

```
        AuthenticationResult result = null;
        try
        {
            string[] scopeDefault = new string[] { "MyString" };
            result = await app.AcquireTokenForClient(scopeDefault).ExecuteAsync();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception(ex.Message);
        }
```

I must be missing something. Any clues anyone ?
Thanks

Phil

Comment: Can you include the code where you "try and use" the string array - that is the important part really.

Comment: Hi, here it is: 
```
            AuthenticationResult result = null; 
            try
            {
                string[] scopeDefault = new string[] { "MyString" };
                result = await app.AcquireTokenForClient(scopeDefault).ExecuteAsync();
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception(ex.Message);
            }```

Comment: @MisterMagoo apologies - I am new to StackOverflow and couldn't get the inline formatting of the code block to work properly. I have amended the original post to make it more readable.

Comment: That's great - I don't think the problem is the string[] - Is this Microsoft.Identity.Web ? I'm not going to be any help with that because I haven't used it.